# Is $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}$ surjective?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

The domain was given to be $\mathbb{R}$. I calculated that the range was $(0,1]$ and that for every $y$ I could find an $x$ in that domain since $x = \sqrt{\frac{1}{y^{2}}-1}$. I therefore thought $f(x)$ was surjective, but when I asked Wolfram Alpha it said that it isn't surjective, because it isn't surjective on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Of course, surjectivity will depend on what _codomain_ the function has.

Comment: Yep. How can $f(x)$ be $0$?

Comment: You are using $Range$ as the codomain.

Answer (score 2):

It depends upon the codomain we are assuming for $f$, indeed if we consider

$$f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$$

it is not surjective since for example $\not \exists x$ such that $f(x)=-1$ but if we assume

$$f: \mathbb{R}\to (0,1]$$

it is surjective and for a suitable restriction of the ("natural") domain

$$f: [0,\infty) \to (0,1]$$

it is also injective and thus bijective, that is invertible.

Refer also to the related

- [Why is $\sin : \mathbb{R} \to [-5,5] $ different from $\sin : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2866897/505767)