# What does $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ mean?

Tags: functions, notation, real-numbers

This is simply a basic notation question: what is the meaning of
$$f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$$
I imagine it's some sort of function to do with the set of real numbers, perhaps some sort of mapping. Until now I've only encountered functions of the form
$$f(x)=...$$
or $$f:x\mapsto...$$
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can read this as "$f$ is a function that maps from the reals to the reals."  It doesn't tell you anything else about what that function is.

Comment: It looks as if you are already aware of the 2 ways to define a function. First we define the domain and co-domain ($f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$). Then we define the actual mapping with either $f(x)=\ldots$ or $f:x\mapsto\ldots$. Sometimes the definition of domain and co-domain is left out if it is considered obvious from the context.

Comment: @arjun Not range, but codomain.

Comment: The term "range" is considered ambiguous as it could either be the codomain or the image of the domain. Best to avoid it.

Comment: Refer also to [What is a function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1087412/505767)

Comment: @user thanks, that looks very informative.

Comment: @A-levelStudent There is a lot of material on MSE, also this [OP](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2866897/505767) could be useful. You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that the function maps any real number (all real numbers are the domain) to one and only one real number (the codomain is a subset of $\mathbb R$).

For example the following notations are valid

- $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R,\: f(x)=x^3$
- $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R,\: f(x)=x^2$
- $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R^+_0,\: f(x)=x^2$
- $f:\mathbb R^+_0 \rightarrow \mathbb R^+_0,\: f(x)=\sqrt x$

and the following are wrong

- $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R^+_0,\: f(x)=\sqrt x$
- $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R,\: f(x)=\log x$
- $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R,\: f(x)=\frac 1x$

Comment: Given a function, is it possible to find the codomain? For example, can you find the codomain of $f(x)=x^2$?

Comment: @A-levelStudent Yes of course, in this case since $x^2\ge 0$ we have that the codomain is any $U\subseteq \mathbb R$ such that $\mathbb R^+_0\subseteq U$.

Answer (score 3):

It means that $f$ is a function with domain $\Bbb R$ and codomain $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Just to doublecheck: codomain is simply the range?

Comment: All the values are reals.  But it is possible that some reals are not values.  Some texts use "range" for the set of values of $f$.  Thus the use of "codomain" where the set of values might or might not be all of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @A-levelStudent The *range* is the collection of all the numbers that you can reach with the function, the *codomain* is simply a set that contains the range.

Comment: @A-levelStudent: "Range" is often used more specifically to refer to the set of values that are actually mapped to from the domain.  If the function is surjective ("onto"), then they are the same.  For example, the function $\sin x$ can be said to be $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, but the range is $[-1, 1]$.

Comment: Typically, range is the set $\{f(x)\,:\, x\in\operatorname{dom}f\}$, whereas a codomain for $f$ is just a set $B$ such that $f(x)\in B$ for all $x\in\operatorname{dom}f$. Often, context pushes for one set being chosen as codomain rather than others.

Comment: @ Azif00 what else could be in the codomain (as it's a set) apart from the range?

Comment: The codomain must contain the range, but could contain other values.  See my earlier comment for an example.

Comment: @A-levelStudent For example consider $f : [0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ given by $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$. Then the range of $f$ is $[0,\infty)$ since the square root is always non-negative.

Comment: @BrianTung Often Codomain and Range are used as synonyms and Image is used to indicate the set of all $f(x)$ with $x$ in the domain.

Comment: @A-levelStudent See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_of_a_function)

Comment: @user: I know.  That's why I only said that "range" is "often used more specifically..." :-)

Comment: @Gae.S. thanks for that, that was really helpful. Does that mean that the codomain for all functions with real domains is simply $\mathbb R$, as the codomain eg for $f(x)=x^2$ is irrelevant to the actual function?

Comment: @BrianTung Sorry I didn't see your first comment! That's fine we agree with that definition. Sometimes it's not the case! (as for the "divergent" and the "not existing" case for limits). Regards

Comment: @A-levelStudent Nothing of sort. It means that the function $f$, specifically, has domain $\Bbb R$ and codomain $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @Gae.S. ok... so in the case of $f(x)=x^2$ with codomain $\mathbb R$, what is the relevance of the codomain to the function?

Comment: @A-levelStudent: It means that every value the function takes on (as output) falls within the reals.  If you're familiar with function declarations in computing languages, it's like declaring that a function takes a float as input, and produces a float as output (except of course that reals are not floats).  That declaration does *not* means that every float can be produced as an output; it just says that all outputs are floats.

Comment: @BrianTung , thanks for that. Unfortuantely I'm unfamiliar with computer languages, but thanks to your and Gae.S,' and everyone's combined efforts I think I understand now, so thank you to all who helped :)